# Does HaShem ever say I Love you?

Tags: love

Is there anywhere in the scripture where HaShem says "I love you." or "I love"? Directly and not indirectly.

Comment: @DoubleAA All the answers given are in the past tense and do not answer the question.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE, actually, Biblical Hebrew doesn't really have tenses. The two answers given so far quote verses that if you were being hyper-literal would be in the perfect aspect. There is just no way to write an English translation without tense. In any case, tenses and G-d only have meaning when talking about when His Action has consequences in this universe, with its notion of time. G-d doesn't experience Time "first-hand", He causes it after all. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) But the same is true of emotions. G-d doesn't have emotions, G-d's actions reach us in ways that we interpret as being motivated by an emotion. Which is, after all, how we assesss how other people are feeling emotionally. (Though there we assume people's emotions are real, if inaccessible to me.) So, when G-d loves someone really boils down to when does G-d's Action reach the world in a manner that we would assess as loving.

Comment: @MichaBerger Love is an emergent attribute (in the sense that love is not something that can be perceived with the 5 senses and that it can only be perceived by the effect it has on the object of the love and that it is not an attribute of any part of the lover, i.e. it is not that my left arm loves you and my nose loves you, just that I love you), so if I say that "I love you" in the present tense, this means that my love is evidenced by my ongoing, future actions. So if meaning the present, the *passuk* should tend to the future.

Comment: An argument can be made that G-d does not have emotions and the term "love" is used as a poetic way of saying the Jews discovered G-d (ie Abraham discovered G-d).

Comment: @MichaBerger I agree with you that G-d does not have emotions. I do not think that G-d has emotions. This is also the view of Rambam.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Love is something that science can't prove but exists. Yet, it would be wrong to associate "love" with G-d. It is almost an insult to say "G-d loves you," because G-d loves you more than you could possibly imagine, and for us, simple limited finite beings to say G-d loves you, diminished His glory and what it means to be loved by G-d.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I heard the idea from a Reform rabbi.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE, notice that the fist answer was posted by the questioner, so apparently he wasn't referring to present tense as opposed to past.

Comment: @TurkHill *Bechol kavod harauy*, I think that is an absurd notion.

Comment: @Mordechai Agreed

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I think the world was created for the animals, too.

Comment: @TurkHill Certainly according to the *hakdamah* of the Ramban to his *peyrush* on the Torah, understanding animals is one of the 50 gates to understanding Hashem.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Yes, that is correct, Ramban is correct.

Comment: I always thought that the whole of Scripture was expressing this very thing indirectly!

Answer (score 9):

Deuteronomy 7:8 the Lord loved you and kept the oath which He swore to your forefathers

Jeremiah 31:3 The Lord appeared to him long ago, saying, “I have loved you with an everlasting love; Therefore I have drawn you out with kindness.

Hosea 11:1 When Israel was a youth I loved him, And out of Egypt I called My son.

Answer (score 6):

> אָהַבְתִּי אֶתְכֶם אָמַר יְהוָה וַאֲמַרְתֶּם בַּמָּה אֲהַבְתָּנוּ הֲלוֹא־אָח עֵשָׂו לְיַעֲקֹב נְאֻם־יְהוָה וָאֹהַב אֶת־יַעֲקֹב׃
>
> I have shown you love, said the LORD. But you ask, “How have You shown us love?” After all—declares the LORD—Esau is Jacob’s brother; yet I have accepted Jacob

[Malachai 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.1.2)

Comment: You might want to correct the translation. At least use brackets around the "shown you/us". The original Hebrew and Targum Yonasan's "רְחִימֵית יַתְכוֹן", answers the question far more clearly in the affirmative than does the JPS translation.

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 43:4 - "Since you are precious and honored in my sight, and because **I love you**, I will give people in exchange for you, nations in exchange for your life." (Emphasis mine)

Comment: Not bad for a doofus

Comment: Just setting expectations. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Pirkie Avos 3/14](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.14?lang=bi)

חבִיבִין יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁנִּקְרְאוּ בָנִים לַמָּקוֹם. חִבָּה יְתֵרָה נוֹדַעַת לָהֶם שֶׁנִּקְרְאוּ בָנִים לַמָּקוֹם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יד) בָּנִים אַתֶּם לַה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם. חֲבִיבִין יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁנִּתַּן לָהֶם כְּלִי חֶמְדָּה. חִבָּה יְתֵרָה נוֹדַעַת לָהֶם שֶׁנִּתַּן לָהֶם כְּלִי חֶמְדָּה שֶׁבּוֹ נִבְרָא הָעוֹלָם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי ד) כִּי לֶקַח טוֹב נָתַתִּי לָכֶם, תּוֹרָתִי אַל תַּעֲזֹבוּ:

Beloved are Israel in that they were called children to the All-Present. Especially beloved are they for it was made known to them that they are called children of the All-Present, as it is said: “your are children to the Lord your God” (Deuteronomy 14:1). Beloved are Israel in that a precious vessel was given to them. Especially beloved are they for it was made known to them that the desirable instrument, with which the world had been created, was given to them, as it is said: “for I give you good instruction; forsake not my teaching” (Proverbs 4:2).

Answer (score -3):

The Kuzari writes that G-d loves Jews. Deuteronomy 7:6, for example, states that, “you are a people consecrated to the L-rd your G-d: of all the people on earth the L-rd your G-d chose you to be His treasured people.” Deuteronomy 7:7–8 says that God chose the Jews “because the L-rd loved you.”